# pyspark stream does not read delta lake change data feed in an order

Tags: spark-streaming, databricks, delta-lake

```py
df = spark.readStream.option("readChangeFeed", "true")\
  .option("startingVersion", 2)\
  .load(hubble_account_tablePath)

display(df)
```

this returns unordered change data feed. Any suggestions to get the change data feed in asc order as a continuous stream?

Comment: `display` is by definition. Please write what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexOtt Thanks for the response. I need to send the change data feed to  azure event hub. I want to make sure that all the old cdc version data  should flow in the order which they were committed. for example if current commit version is 25 and I start the stream from 2 as above , stream should write data in asc order of commit version(version 2..version 3... version 25).

Comment: @AlexOtt Could you please suggest something on this?

Answer (score 0):

Think you can order by commitVersion

```
df = spark.readStream.option("readChangeFeed", "true")\
  .option("startingVersion", 2)\
  .load(hubble_account_tablePath)
.orderBy("commitVersion")

display(df)
```

Comment: Sorting is not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets, unless it is on aggregated DataFrame/Dataset in Complete output mode;